# Tomcat server error: 503 Service Temporarily Unavailable

Tags: http-status-code-503, tomcat

the server was running fine the last few months then suddenly today and yesterday it just stop responding and returned the 503 error. it works when i restarted the server but in a few hours, it stops again and returns the 503 error. The problem is i don't know what causes the problem time to time. i checked the error log and the file size is too large; could this be the problem of the sudden error on the tomcat server?

Any Help Will do

Comment: This may help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6299086/how-to-detect-cause-of-503-service-temporarily-unavailable-error-and-handle-it?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

Best to tail the log files, when the error occurs and debug from there. If the log files are too large, zero them out, make a backup of it, and restart Tomcat and try.