# Apache throwing 500 after 30 seconds

Tags: php, apache, timeout

I'm running Apache2 and PHP5 on a dedicated VPS.

I have a script that should finish anywhere from 20-50 seconds. It works just fine, but if it takes over 30 seconds due to the rows it selected, it instantly kills the script and says:

> "Service Unavailable - The service is temporarily unavailable. Please try again later."

I have `max_execution_time=60`, `max_input_time=60` and `memory_limit=256M` in my php.ini.

In apache2.conf, I have `Timeout=300`.

In the script itself, I'm also using `set_time_limit(0);
ignore_user_abort(true);
ini_set('max_execution_time', 0);
ini_set('memory_limit', '512M');`

No matter what I change the script dies anytime the loading takes over 30.00 seconds and nothing is appearing in any of my logs.

Any suggestions on what other settings to try?

This script is for internal use only and will eventually be running from command line, but I prefer to debug/test from the browser.

Comment: If run time is going to be longer than 15 seconds, it's best not to run it in apache anyway.  Run a process in the background.  Even better, queue a task in beanstalkd and consume it with a separate daemon process.

Answer (score 1):

The error you listed: "Service Unavailable - The service is temporarily unavailable. Please try again later." doesn't sound like a 500 response, it sounds like a 503. Are you sure you are getting back a 500? The [causes for a 503](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6299086/how-to-detect-cause-of-503-service-temporarily-unavailable-error-and-handle-it) would be different.

Answer (score 0):

An internal server error.  Check that all your directives are correct. If you have an **.htaccess** file, make sure you don't have any typos. Other than that, you can debug your script. You maybe changing a setting that triggers the error or conflicts with something else on the server.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have Mod_Security or php-suhosin installed? Those might interfere with the default configurations.