# 503 Service Temporarily Unavailable MyISAM MySQL

Tags: mysql, apache, cpanel

I am making a website, hosted on bigrock.in (`Cpanel` v11.36.1 (build 8), `Apache` version  2.2.24, `PHP` version 5.2.17, `MySQL` version 5.0.84-percona-highperf-b18-log), which insert a lot of entries in a MyISAM table .i.e. say about 200-500 entries. This makes MySQL database to create the following error

```
**503 Service Temporarily Unavailable**

**Service Temporarily Unavailable**
The server is temporarily unable to service your
request due to maintenance downtime or capacity
problems. Please try again later.
Additionally, a 404 Not Found
error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.
```

Thus only some of the data is inserted into the table. What steps should i take to solve this problem.

Comment: This question is off-topic and belongs on [dba.se]

Comment: @FreshPrinceOfSO will this question be automatically moved to dba or should i ask there again?

Comment: After re-reading your question, take a look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6299086/how-to-detect-cause-of-503-service-temporarily-unavailable-error-and-handle-it)